# Activate virtualenv in Ant

Tags: python, ant, virtualenv

Is there a way to activate a newly created virtualenv within an Ant script such that any calls to `<exec executable="python">` (`site-packages` lookups etc) uses the virtualenv and not the global shared path?

I should note that a solution must work on Windows, Linux and Mac.

Comment: Do you just want to use "python" as the path? You could use "<venv>/bin/python".

Comment: @JohnKeyes: Wish it was that easy. I need to activate the virtualenv so that any installed packages (using any number of installation methods) use the virtualenv and not the system-wide paths.

Comment: I thought the path to the executable in the `venv` would do that without the need to call `activate`. When I inspect my `sys.path` it shows the `venv` `site-packages` (and `eggs`) so any packages installed in that `venv` will be used instead of any system-wide ones. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnKeyes: D'oh! Apparently I was missing something. I assumed that python wouldn't resolve to the ``venv`` packages unless it was explicitly activated. Please move your comments down to an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer directly to the executable in the `virtualenv`:

```
<exec executable="<virtual_env_dir>/bin/python">
...
```

This will automatically use the packages installed in the `virtualenv` rather than those in the base install.